# Console log not firing in promise on android device

Tags: android, angular, debugging, ionic3, device

I'm developing an Ionic app in which I try to load the device's contacts using native plugin. There's an asynchronous call with some console logs inside but the logs are not appearing when run on android 5.1 device. The rest of the code in promise are fired, only the logs are not fired. In the browser, they appear.

```
public loadContactsFromDevice(): void {
  console.log('ContactsProvider loadContactsFromDevice INIZIO');//this is fired
  this.contacts.find(
    ['displayName', 'name', 'birthday'],
    { filter: "", multiple: true })
    .then(resultData => {
      console.log('ContactsProvider loadContactsFromDevice resultData:' + resultData);//this is not fired
      this.allContacts = resultData;
      this.setContactsList(this.allContacts);
    });
  console.log('ContactsProvider loadContactsFromDevice FINE');//this is fired
}
```

Comment: Could you post more code about android app or more details about your issue?

Comment: What is `this.contacts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Previously I put the call to method that retrives the contacts in app.component.ts inside`platform.ready().then(){}` .. When i put it outside the platform.ready() the logs are visible. I don't know why but it works.